# How can i get the android support library version greater than 47

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have the latest stable Android Studio 3.2.1 installed (along with Android Studio Preview 3.3) and it offers only the version 47 of the support library repository in the SDK manager. This repository doesn't contain versions 26, 27 or 28 of the libraries (it contains 26.0.0-alpha1).

How can i make my local (~/Library/Android/sdk/extras on Mac) contain the missing versions?

All i've found are guides to add these libraries to gradle config, but i need the actual AAR-files, since i'm trying to resolve conflicts in a Unity project.

I've tried downloading version 48 manually from
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r48.zip
but that's a 404. Only the version 47 is available in
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip

Now i'm extremely puzzled why the latest stable release of Android Studio won't give me up to date support libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup) page:

> The support libraries are now available through Google's Maven repository. We no longer support downloading the libraries through the SDK Manager, and that functionality will be removed soon..

Instead, you just simply include them by adding the `google()` Maven repo. Put this in your top-level build.gradle's `repositories` section:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

Then you can just implement the support libraries in your app-level build.gradle.

Comment: Doesn't really solve my problem, but i guess the correct answer is that it's impossible to achieve this.